# SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false: Does Sharepoint keep this setting?

Tags: security, access-denied, exception-handling

When I add `SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;` this disables the redirection to a login site.

Does Sharepoint keep that setting until I set it to "true" or just as long until the object is disposed?

Or in other words:
I want to be able to change that setting globally. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kept inside the current HttpContext. If you decompile the code you will see it:

```
public static bool CatchAccessDeniedException
{
  get
  {
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    if (current == null)
      return false;
    string str = (string) current.Items[(object) "CatchAccessDenied"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
      return str.Equals("TRUE", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    else
      return true;
  }
  set
  {
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    if (current == null)
      return;
    current.Items[(object) "CatchAccessDenied"] = value ? (object) "TRUE" : (object) "FALSE";
  }
}
```

So the setting you make is valid during the HttpRequest lifecycle.